# Do all intel gpu's use software rendering (Mesa) only?

Tags: debian, graphics, intel

I was looking at :-

```
$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile 
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 11.0.7
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 11.0.7
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 11.0.7
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

From the above, this bit -

```
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile
```

seems to say that it is all using software rendering, how do I turn on the hardware rendering if I want to ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably use hardware rendering, check this:

```
$ glxinfo | fgrep direct
direct rendering: Yes
```

"Direct rendering" above is explained by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Rendering_Infrastructure) as:

> The **Direct Rendering Infrastructure (DRI)** is a framework for allowing direct access to graphics hardware under the X Window System in a safe, efficient way. The main use of DRI is to provide hardware acceleration for the Mesa implementation of OpenGL.

As pointed out by @Ruslan, Mesa contains a software renderer to use as a fallback when no graphics hardware accelerator is available. It's called *Gallium* in `OpenGL renderer string`. But your output shows that the Intel renderer is being used, not the software one.

Comment: so if it says direct rendering: Yes, does it mean that it doesn't use software i.e. Mesa, am I to understand that ?

Comment: It still uses Mesa, because that's your OpenGL implementation. But Mesa uses your graphics hardware in this case.

Comment: Your test is inconclusive. One can get `direct rendering: Yes` with software rasterizer: try `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 glxinfo|grep ^direct` on a properly setup system.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely use hardware rendering. Software renderer has another name:

```
$ LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 glxinfo|grep '\<renderer\>'
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.5, 256 bits)
```

To easily check you can simply compare the output of the above command with what you get without `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1`. If it gives identical output, you're using software renderer by default. Otherwise it's most likely hardware accelerated.